# General solutions of $ \sin (A) = \sin (B)$

Tags: trigonometry

In my text book it is directly stated that the general solution of the equation
 $ \sin (A) = \sin (B)$ , is

$ A = 2n\pi + B$   and     $A = (2n +1)\pi - B$

but where is the second solution coming from? Since period of $\sin$ function is $2\pi$, shouldn't the solutions be, $ A = 2n\pi + B$ and $ A = 2n\pi - B$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say, $ \sin (A) = \sin (B) = s$ , from this we can approach the solution by finding the solution set of $ \sin (B) = s$ , since $ \sin (A) = s$ , we can say that 
$ A = $ solution set of $B$. Lets solve, $ \sin (B) = s$
We will use Principal Values, Secondary Values and quadrant diagrams to approach the solution and convey clarity. 
there are two possible cases, one where $s\ge 0 $ and the other where $ s \le 0$.
For the case where $s\ge 0 $, the required solution will lie in the 1st or the 2nd quadrant as shown below:[image: Quadrant Diagram]

and the case where $ s \le 0$, the solution will lie in the 3rd or the 4th quadrant, as shown below:
[image: Quadrant Diagram 2]

so the general solution should give formula that will help generate the infinite set of angles. The formula(s) in question should address all the four lines, namely, PV+ , SV+, PV-, SV- and in order to generate the complete solution set for the complete range $ -1\le s \le1$

The first solution $ A = 2n\pi + B$ , is for the solutions of PV+ or PV- depending on the value of $s$. Any rotation of angles of $2n\pi$ will result in the position shown below:[image: Quadrant Image 3]

Lets say the PV+ is   $\theta$  and $\theta > 0$ and acute , when $ \sin (B) = s$ and $ s \ge 0$.

Also lets say the PV- is   $\beta$  and $\beta < 0$ and acute , when $ \sin (B) = s$ and $ s \le 0$.
(Note: plugging $\beta$ into $A = 2n\pi + B$ is a subtraction as $\beta < 0$)

The diagrams below should clarify how $ A = 2n\pi + B$ gives solutions for PV+ and PV-:
[image: QD4]

[image: QD5]
(Note: plugging $\beta$ into $A = 2n\pi + B$ is a subtraction as $\beta < 0$)
Recall:
Lets say the PV+ is   $\theta$  and $\theta > 0$ and acute , when $ \sin (B) = s$ and $ s \ge 0$.
Also lets say the PV- is   $\beta$  and $\beta < 0$ and acute , when $ \sin (B) = s$ and $ s \le 0$.
PV or principal value is also the associated acute angle.

The second solution $A = (2n+1)\pi - B$ gives the solutions for SV+ and SV-.
any rotation of angles of $(2n+1)\pi$ will result in the position shown below:
[image]

 So $ (2n+1)\pi - \theta$ gives all solution for the SV+ location, while $ (2n+1)\pi - \beta$ gives us all the solution for the SV- location. 
(Note: Since $\beta<0$, $ (2n+1)\pi - \beta$  is essentially an addition)

The diagrams below should clarify how the general formula leads to SV+ and SV-:
[image]
[image]
(Note: Since $\beta<0$, $ (2n+1)\pi - \beta$  is essentially an addition)

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$\sin (180-\theta)=\sin(??)$

Comment: that would be $\sin (\theta)$, so, that would result in $ A = - B$ for $A = 2n\pi -B$ ?

Comment: **$A=−B$ for $A=2n\pi−B$**???? I do not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: sorry, I got the wrong idea, just figured it out, but what about 
$\sin (180^\circ - \theta) = \sin (\theta)$? what should I infer from this?

Comment: $A=(2n+1)\pi-B\Rightarrow \sin(A)=\sin((2n+1)\pi -B)=\sin (2n\pi +\pi -B)=\sin(\pi -B)=????$ Can you conclude now?

Comment: yes I get it now.. I was thinking around similar lines in my first comment:
if $ A = 2n\pi -B$ was a solution, 
$ \sin (2n\pi - B) = - \sin (B)$ as we know that $\sin (2\pi - \alpha) = -\alpha$  this would result in $ \sin (A) = - \sin (B)$ and this would contradict the original equation and thus it cannot be a solution.

Comment: we know that B could any angle and there are four possibilities 
$\pm$ acute B  or $\pm$ obtuse B. Now if we use the solutions above in your diagram, we get solutions for position 1 and 2, how do we get solutions for angles in quadrants 3 and 4?

Comment: sine is negative in third and fourth quadrant... so, there are no solutions for that in third and fourth quadrant

Answer (score 0):

Look at the unit circle:

[image]

The y-coordinate is equal for both positions $1$ and $2$.

It remains to realise that:

Position 1) is $2n\pi +x$

Position 2) is $(2n+1)\pi-x$

**EDIT**:
[image: Apologies for the messy picture, it's always messy in MSPaint]

I'm not really sure if this is what you meant. It's just an example though.

Comment: yes the edited diagram seems, correct, but playing around with the general solutions with different values and comparing with the $\sin$ curve and the unit circle helped to understand the solution.

Comment: we know that B could any angle and there are four possibilities 
$\pm$ acute B  or $\pm$ obtuse B. Now if we use the solutions above in your diagram, we get solutions for position 1 and 2, how do we get solutions for angles in quadrants 3 and 4?

Comment: The required solutions(if you _want_ them to be -ve) can be obtained using suitable **-ve** values of n(they're allowed of course)

Comment: Also, consider the unit circle as just a means of better visualization. The _real_ thing would be this : $\sin((2n +1)\pi - B)=\sin B$. Try and prove it!

Answer (score 0):

#### Equation

The general solution of the equation sin(A) = sin(B) is given by:
$A = B + (-1)^n nπ$

#### EDIT: Proof

Here is the proof for the above equation. we are given: 
$sin(A) = sin(B)$ 
=> $sin(A)-sin(B)=0$ 
=> $2cos(\frac{A+B}{2})sin(\frac{A-B}{2}) = 0$ 
=> $cos(\frac{A+B}{2})=0$ or $sin(\frac{A-B}{2})=0$ 
=> $\frac{A+B}{2}=(2n+1)π/2$ or $\frac{A-B}{2}=nπ$ 
=> $A=(2n+1)π–B$ or $A=2nπ+B$ 
=> $A = (2n+1)π+(–1)^{2n + 1} B$ or $x = 2nπ +(–1)^{2n}B$ 
Combining both the equations we get, 
$A = nπ + (–1)^n B$

Comment: welcome to MSE. would be good to have some explaination of how you arrive at that.