# If $\alpha=\frac38\pi$, and $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<2\pi$ with $\sin\alpha=\sin\theta$, then how do we find $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

> $\alpha=\frac38\pi$ rad. Angle $\theta$ is such that $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<2\pi$ and $\sin(\alpha)=sin(\theta)$.
>
> How to find $\theta$?

Trigonometry has never been my strongest point in math, i know this should be an easy exercise.

Comment: We get $$\theta=\frac{5}{8}\pi$$

Comment: What do you know about the sine function? Make a list, some of the properties ought to help.

Comment: Take arcsin of both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\theta = \pi - \frac{3}{8}\pi$, we have the result. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807581/general-solutions-of-sin-a-sin-b) for more details.

Comment: Thank you all very much. It totally makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, you can see that $\theta = \pi - \alpha$. I let you the proof after having visualized this on the unit circle ;)